# Should perform segue on request

Tags: swift, asynchronous, swift3, alamofire, grand-central-dispatch

i'm starting with Swift3 and i'm having a recurrent problem due to the asynchronism. But until now, i always find a solution with callback.

I have a textField and a button, when i click on the button, i check on the API if there is a existing user named as in the textField.

Using `shouldPerformSegue`, i return the value if the users exist or no.

I have a separated class for handling calls on the Api

```
class Api {
    static let urlApi = "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    private let CUSTOMER_ID = "XXXXXXXX"
    private let CUSTOMER_SECRET = "XXXXXXXX"

    private var access_token : String? = nil

    private var userInfo : User?

    init() {
        self.connect()
    }

    func connect() {
       // Do the connect...
    }

    func get(user: String, callback: @escaping (_ status: Bool) -> Void) {
        Alamofire.request(URL(string: "\(Api.urlApi)/v2/users/\(user)")!,
                          method: .get,
                          parameters: nil,
                          encoding: URLEncoding.default,
                          headers: ["Authorization": "Bearer \(self.access_token!)"])
            .responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
                if response.result.isFailure {
                    print("ERROR: GET USER", response)
                    callback(false)
                } else {
                    print("SUCCESS Getting user ", user)
                    callback(true)
                }
            })
    }
}
```

And in my `shouldPerformSegue`

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    var userExist : Bool? = nil
    let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "getUser")
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)

    dispatchQueue.sync {

        self.api?.get(user: self.userTextField.text!, callback: { status in
            userExist = status
            print("1 USEREXIST", userExist)
        })
    }
    semaphore.wait()
    print("2 USEREXIST", userExist)
    return userExist ?? false // always false because userExist == nil
}
```

Sorry for the function mess, i don't really find the right way to do my `DispachQueue` and my `Semaphore` .. All googling answer look that i need those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to handle this scenario would be to make the request when the user taps on the button. If there is an error, you would present some error that says the username already exists. Then they would try again.

If the request is successful and that username has not been taken, then you would call `performSegueWithIdentifier`. The link below shows a good demonstration of the steps to take after this. Your current implementation isn't necessary.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37823730/653839

Comment: Ok for that, but for the knowledge, how to do it like i would first ?

Comment: @ale-batt You haven't posted what the results of your print statements are generating so I could not tell you. If the user exists, then you would want to return false, so technically your logic is incorrect for the return statement.

Comment: @ale-batt Okay that might be an indication that your request never gets called. You are using an optional on your `self.api?`. Is your api object initialized in your class? It's to determine what the cause is without seeing the necessary code.